# What to return for jQuery's ajax data param in callback function?

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, return

I use jQuery's ajax function to call a url asynchron like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    data: {key : value},
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
}
```

On the server side I don't know what to return to get something meaningful inside the variable `data`. The console's log is just empty string.

I already tried `return 0`, `return 1`, `return array('status' => 1)`, `return true`

Background: I want to know if any exceptions have been thrown on the server side to pass something like false or true if it was successful without exceptions.

EDIT: Server side language is PHP

Comment: What server-side language are you using? does `return` in that language output html to the page?

Comment: What is your server side language? PhP, Ruby, C#,..? Also, what does the server side method look like?

Comment: PHP, no its not html which will be returned

Comment: @tester html, text, json, it's all the same, just text.

Comment: @tester: `I don't know what to return to get something meaningful inside the variable data`. We commonly return a JSON object which contains the HTML or what ever data in one property, for example: `data.returnValue`, another property which contains an array of violation objects, i.e: `data.violations` and another containing a status like `Success/Error`, i.e: `data.status` (That one could be a boolean too I suppose). They are custom object we understand in the receiving end but you can design your own off course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using PHP, you would just echo a string return value.

```
echo "true";
exit;
```

or

```
echo "false";
exit;
```

then you can parse that with jQuery:

```
if ( $.trim(data) == "true" ) {
    console.log("success!")
}
else {
    console.log(data);
}
```

You could also echo 0 or 1, but keep in mind it's still a string, not a number when it gets to jQuery. For more complex data, such as an array, you can json_encode it.

```
echo json_encode( $myarray );
exit;
```

and set your `dataType` to `"json"` in jQuery's `$.ajax` method.

Comment: we'd need to see your php then.