# Yii2 - beforeSubmit ajax return value

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii, yii2

I am doing an AJAX call in my `beforeSubmit()` function, as follows:

```
$('#register-form').on('beforeSubmit', function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(response) {
            return response.status; // boolean
        }
    });
});
```

I want the result of the AJAX success function (`true` or `false`) to determine the return value of the `beforeSubmit()` function.

I realise that you can't return within ajax success, I'm also aware a potential solution to this would be to set `async: false` in my AJAX call, however I know this isn't recommended, so would prefer to try a different solution.

I have tried to implement a "callback" function as detailed in these posts:

[ajax return true/false - I have implemented a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078650/ajax-return-true-false-i-have-implemented-a-callback)

[jQuery: Return data after ajax call success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success/5316755)

But I still cannot seem to get it to work.

Comment: what have you done so far following the above given posts? what happens that you decide to say it is not working?

Comment: if you are thinking that you can continue to submit the  form or stop the submission of the form based on returning the ajax `response.status` it wont work, you would have to manually submit the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this as follows:

```
$('#register-form').on('beforeSubmit', function(event) {
    var form = $(this);

    if (!form.hasClass('complete')) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.status == true) {
                    form.addClass('complete').submit();
                }
            }
        });

        return false;
    }
});
```

So the `beforeSubmit()` function only returns false if the form does not have class 'complete'. If it does, it will proceed with default form submission.

Comment: `beforeSubmit()` is a Yii2 `ActiveForm.js` function, not jQuery.